# string as type of varchar in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, plugins

i am inserting values iput by  users that is two arrays ROOMTILTIE AND CAPACITY.. RoomTitle is varchar and capacity is intger type when i entered string such as "2s32" and capacity any integer value it does not insert it into the table but when both are integer then it works perfectly.. below is the code

```
     <form name="venueform"   method="post" >
     <input type="hidden" name="check_submit" value="1" id="check_submit" />
     <table width="450px">
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td valign="top"">
            <label for="TotalRooms">Total Number of Rooms*</label>
            </td>

            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="TotalRooms" maxlength="50" size="10"id='sth'>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
                <input name="submit1 "type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </form>

     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
     mysql_select_db("ossd");
    for($i=0;$i<$_POST['TotalRooms'];$i++)
    {

    echo"<p>\n</p>";
    ?><form method="post">
   <input type="text" name='RoomTitle[]' /><br />
   <input type="text" name='Capacity[]' /><br />
   echo"<input name='addvenue' type='submit'value='Submit me' />
   </form>";
  if (isset($_POST['addvenue'])) {

  <div>
   <?php echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST['RoomTitle'],true)."</pre>";
   echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST['Capacity'],true)."</pre>";

   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
   mysql_select_db("ossd");
   foreach ($_POST['RoomTitle'] as $row=>$name)

  {

    $RoomTitle = $name;

    $Capacity = $_POST['Capacity'][$row];
    $RoomTitle= mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $Capacity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Capacity'][$row]);

    $order = "INSERT INTO wp_ossd_venue
        (RoomTitle,Capacity)
        VALUES
        (".$RoomTitle.",".$Capacity.")";

     $result = mysql_query($order);

     }
    if($result){
    echo("<br>Succesfully Added");
    } else{
     echo("<br>Fail... Error");
    }

    }
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: the values is not inserting in the table if its string like "2s32" but if both the Roomtitle and capacity are of integer typee then its work good... here is the table                                     id int(11)                                          UNSIGNED RoomTitle varchar(25) utf8_general_ci         Capacity int(11)

Comment: Use `echo mysql_error()` in your `else` at the end to see the obvious syntax error you're producing.

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert query should be :

```
$order = "INSERT INTO wp_ossd_venue
        (RoomTitle,Capacity)
        VALUES
        ('".$RoomTitle."',".$Capacity.")";
```